# Python Iterating through a directory xml files

Tags: python, xml, csv

A stackoverflow user helped me big time by helping me parse an XML file to a csv file.  It was so helpful that I decided to try to iterate through an entire directory and parse all the xml files to a single csv file.  Here's the code that works:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv

extra_columns = 2

fields = [
('Id_Customer', 'Id_Customer', 1),
('Segment', 'Segment', 1),
('Nature', 'Event/Nature', 1),
('Extrainfo', 'Event/Extrainfo', 1),
('zipcode', 'Adress/zipcode', extra_columns),
('street', 'Adress/street', extra_columns),
('number', 'Adress/number', extra_columns)]

tree = ET.parse('cat.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

# Auto create the header from fields
fieldnames = []

for field, match, cols in fields:
   fieldnames.append(field)

if cols > 1:
    fieldnames.extend(["{}{}".format(field, x+2) for x in range(extra_columns)])

with open(r'customerdata.csv', 'wb') as f_customerdata:
    csv_customerdata = csv.DictWriter(f_customerdata, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_customerdata.writeheader()

for node in tree.iter('Customer'):
    row = {}

    for field_name, match, cols in fields:
        if cols > 1:
            for index, el in enumerate(node.findall(match)):
                try:
                    if index:
                        row["{}{}".format(field_name, index+1)] = el.text
                    else:
                        row[field_name] = el.text

                except AttributeError as e:
                    row[field_name] = ''
        else:
            try:
                row[field_name] = node.find(match).text
            except AttributeError as e:
                row[field_name] = ''

    csv_customerdata.writerow(row)
```

Then I tried to introduce the listdir to find all the file names (and this step works):

```
for filename in os.path.join(r'C:\docs', filename):
    if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
    fullname = os.path.join(r'C:\docs', filename)
```

However, when I try to integrate the steps I'm finding I'm only getting data from the first xml file in the directory.  See merged code below.  I'm trying to figure out why my for loop is not iterating and writing each parsed xml file to the csv file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import csv
import os

extra_columns = 2

fields = [
('Id_Customer', 'Id_Customer', 1),
('Segment', 'Segment', 1),
('Nature', 'Event/Nature', 1),
('Extrainfo', 'Event/Extrainfo', 1),
('zipcode', 'Adress/zipcode', extra_columns),
('street', 'Adress/street', extra_columns),
('number', 'Adress/number', extra_columns)]

#tree = ET.parse('cat.xml')
#root = tree.getroot()

# Auto create the header from fields
fieldnames = []

with open(r'customerdata.csv', 'wb') as f_customerdata:
    csv_customerdata = csv.DictWriter(f_customerdata, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_customerdata.writeheader()

    for filename in os.listdir(r'C:\docs'):
        if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
        fullname = os.path.join(r'C:\docs',filename)
        tree = ET.parse(fullname)
        root = tree.getroot()

        for node in tree.iter('Customer'):
            row = {}

            for field_name, match, cols in fields:
                if cols > 1:
                    for index, el in enumerate(node.findall(match)):
                        try:
                            if index:
                                row["{}{}".format(field_name, index+1)] = el.text
                            else:
                                row[field_name] = el.text

                        except AttributeError as e:
                            row[field_name] = ''
            else:
                try:
                    row[field_name] = node.find(match).text
                except AttributeError as e:
                    row[field_name] = ''

   csv_customerdata.writerow(row)
```

Updated:

```
with open(r'customerdata.csv', 'wb') as f_customerdata:
    csv_customerdata = csv.DictWriter(f_customerdata, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_customerdata.writeheader()

for filename in os.listdir(r'C:\docs'):
     if not filename.endswith('.xml'): continue
     fullname = os.path.join(r'C:\docs',filename)
     tree = ET.parse(fullname)
     root = tree.getroot()

     for node in tree.iter('Customer'):
         row = {}
         for field_name, match, cols in fields:
             if cols > 1:
                 for index, el in enumerate(node.findall(match)):
                     try:
                         if index:
                             row["{}{}".format(field_name, index+1)] = el.text
                         else:
                             row[field_name] = el.text

                     except AttributeError as e:
                         row[field_name] = ''
            else:
                try:
                    row[field_name] = node.find(match).text
                except AttributeError as e:
                    row[field_name] = ''

       csv_customerdata.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing to the CSV outside of the file loop. The following line should be in the loop going over the files:

```
csv_customerdata.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Since I have made the update of moving the csv_customerdata.writerow(row) to inside the filename for loop, I now get data from every xml file. However, if there are 2 customers in a xml file it's only pulling 1 customer and then moving to the next file.  How can I pull all the customers from the xml file and then move on to the next one?

Comment: Keep in mind each file can a different number of customers.  File 1 could have 5 customers, file 2 could have 1, file 3 could have 2, etc.

Comment: Same issue. Move it into the loop.

Comment: I'm sorry, when I look at the code I'm seeing it is in the loop so obviously I'm not following .  Can you provide an example using the code above so I can visualize it?  Thanks.

Comment: It's not in the internal loop. You should trace the code line by line, preferably with a debugger, and see what's happening. It should be very obvious once you trace it.

Comment: Thanks, I traced it through each section and found the for loop that needed to be adjusted.

Answer (score 0):

Consider no single `for` loop (except loop over the files), `if` logic, or helper dictionary/lists objects. Simply run [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the transformation language that can convert XML to other XML, HTML, and especially for your CSV/TXT files.

However, in order to run an XSLT 1.0 scripts you need Python's third-party module, `lxml`, and not the built-in `etree`. There are [external processors](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) Python can call though even built-in ones such as Window's [System.Xml.Xsl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform(v=vs.110).aspx) and Linux/Mac's [xsltproc](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xsltproc2.html).

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl, another special well-formed .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/CAT">
    <xsl:text>Id_Customer,Segment,Nature,Extrainfo,zipcode,zipcode2,zipcode3,street,street2,street3,number,number2,number3&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Customer"/>            
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="Customer">    
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(Id_Customer, ', ', Segment, ', ', Event/Nature, ', ', Event/Extrainfo, ', ', 
                                   Address[1]/zipcode, ', ', Address[2]/zipcode, ', ', Address[3]/zipcode, ', ', 
                                   Address[1]/street, ', ', Address[2]/street, ', ', Address[3]/street, ', ', 
                                   Address[1]/number, ', ', Address[2]/number, ', ', Address[3]/number)"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>      
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python** *(integrate your XML through this process)*

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL
doc = et.parse('Input.xml')
xsl = et.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

# TRANSFORM XSLT
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)
result = transform(doc)

# SAVE RESULT TO FILE
with open('Output.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(result))
```

**Input** Sample *(extended from previous question post)*

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CAT>
    <Header>...</Header>
    <Add>...</Add>
    <Customer>
        <Id_Customer>xyz1</Id_Customer>
        <Segment>abc1</Segment>
        <Event>
            <Nature>info1</Nature>
            <Extrainfo>info2</Extrainfo>
        </Event>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
        <Id_Customer>zzwy</Id_Customer>
        <Segment>c2</Segment>
        <Address>
            <zipcode>99999</zipcode>
            <street>belaire drive</street>
            <number>5</number>
        </Address>
        <Address>
            <zipcode>88888</zipcode>
            <street>pennsylvania ave</street>
            <number>10</number>
        </Address>
        <Address>
            <zipcode>77777</zipcode>
            <street>main street</street>
            <number>15</number>
        </Address>
    </Customer>
</CAT>
```

**Output**

```
Id_Customer,Segment,Nature,Extrainfo,zipcode,zipcode2,zipcode3,street,street2,street3,number,number2,number3
xyz1, abc1, info1, info2, , , , , , , , , 
zzwy, c2, , , 99999, 88888, 77777, belaire drive, pennsylvania ave, main street, 5, 10, 15
```